# How to make 2 separate h:selectOneRadio tags mutually inclusive of each other?

Tags: jsf

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{abc.def}" id="1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="y" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="y" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="y" />
</h:selectOneRadio>

<h:selectOneRadio value="#{abc.xyz}" id="2">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="y" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="y" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="y" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Above code statements, create separate 3 radio buttons each for id 1, 2.

Selecting radio button on id 1, will toggle other 2 radio buttons. But it won't toggle id 2 radio buttons.

I would like to make all 6 radio buttons mutually inclusive of each other. So the user can select only 1 radio button out of 6.

Please guide me how this is achievable.

Comment: <h:selectOneRadio id="brother" value="#{abc.def}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="y" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="y" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="y" />
  </h:selectOneRadio>

  <h:selectOneRadio id="brother" value="#{abc.xyz}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="y" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="y" />
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="y" />
  </h:selectOneRadio>

Comment: By using above code, i achieved my solution.

Comment: Oh, This is causing id uniqueness error behind the scenes.

Comment: Why don't you just use one `<h:selectOneRadio>`? Is it a purely a presentational/layout problem? Then use `<t:selectOneRadio>`.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. The reason i cannot use one <h:selectOneRadio> because the values are coming from 2 columns behind the scenes. I don't have flexibility to use tomhawk library, however i can use richfaces. But i don't know the solution.